# Как перезаписать значение ключа $data в Codeigniter 3.1.6

Tags: php, codeigniter

В контроллере, в функции `index()` я создаю массив:

```
$data['current_list'] = [
        'id_list' => 0,
        'name_list' => "Не выбран список",
        'date_list' => "0000-00-00",
        'prod_list' =>  [
                        'id_product_list' => 1,
                        'name_product_list' => "",
                        'category_product_list' => "",
                        'amount_product_list' => 0,
                        'price_product_list' => 0
                        ]
        ];
```

Как перезаписать `$data['current_list']['name_list']`, например, в другой функции этого же контроллера? Например, ниже есть функция:

```
public function func1(){
    $data['current_list']['name_list'] = "Новый список";
}
```

Почему `$data['current_list']['name_list']` не изменяется?

Comment: потому что `$data` это локальная переменная. Сделайте ее членом класса `$this->data`, тогда будет доступна и в других функциях, или передавайте как параметр.

Comment: Так сделайте не `$data` а `$this->data`, тогда он будет доступен из любой точки вашего класса. при этом легко можно объявить его приватным (в целях безопасности).

Answer (score 1):

При подобном написании `$data` является локальной переменной. Чтобы она была доступна в других функциях вам следует либо передать ее туда как параметр (`func1($data)`), либо сделать членом класса `$this->data`.

Я, честно сказать, не знаком с CodeIgniter, но обычно `public` методы контроллера реализуют какой-то экшен, и редко вызываются друг из друга. С этой точки зрения, хотелось бы убедиться, что вы рассматриваете передачу данных в рамках выполнения одного и того же GET-запроса.

Comment: `$data` доступна вне функции `index()`. К примеру, моя функция `func1()` находится ниже `index()` и в ней есть такой код":

`$this->load->library('form_validation');

$data['insert'] = array(
 'name' => $this->input->post('name_input'),
 'new_date' => $this->input->post('date_input')
 );
$this->productsout_table_2_model->insert_pdoructs_table_2($data['insert']);`

Как видите, в новой функции я могу создать новый ключ в $data и сразу же положить туда данные, а вот перезаписать не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Всё потому что вы вносите изменения в массив находящийся в области видимости функции,
Изменения не применяются к массиву вне функции. Есть несколько способов решить эту проблему.

Вариант 1 - Передать функции массив, внести в него изменения и ввернуть результат

```
    function func1($data){
        $data['current_list']['name_list'] = "Новый список";
        return $data;
    }

    $data = func1($data);
```

Вариант 2 - Передать функции ссылку на ваш массив

```
    function func2(&$data){
        $data['current_list']['name_list'] = "Новый список";
    }

    func2($data);
```

Вариант 3 - использовать ключевое слово global (не рекомендуется)

```
    function func3(){
        global $data;
        $data['current_list']['name_list'] = "Новый список";
    }

    func3();
```

Про область видимости можно прочитать в [официальной документации PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)